# Numpy: Use vectorization for loop while referring to previous row value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe for which I want to create a column named 'Value' using numpy for fast looping and at the same time refer to the previous row value in the same column.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Product": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"],
        "Inbound": [115, 220, 200, 402, 313, 434, 321, 343, 120],
        "Outbound": [10, 20, 24, 52, 40, 12, 43, 23, 16],
        "Is First?": ["Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No"],
    }
)
```

```
  Product  Inbound  Outbound Is First?  Value
0       A      115        10       Yes    125
1       A      220        20        No    105
2       A      200        24        No     81
3       A      402        52        No     29
4       B      313        40       Yes    353
5       B      434        12        No    341
6       B      321        43        No    298
7       C      343        23       Yes    366
8       C      120        16        No    350
```

The formula for `Value` column in pseudocode is:

```
if ['Is First?'] = 'Yes' then [Value] = [Inbound] + [Outbound]
else [Value] = [Previous Value] - [Outbound]
```

The ideal way of creating the `Value` column right now is to do a `for loop` and use shift to refer to the previous column (which I am somehow not able to make work). But since I will be applying this over a giant dataset, I want to use the numpy vectorization method on it.

```py
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, "Is First?"] == "Yes":
        df.loc[i, "Value"] = df.loc[i, "Inbound"] + df.loc[i, "Outbound"]
    else:
        df.loc[i, "Value"] = df.loc[i, "Value"].shift(-1) + df.loc[i, "Outbound"]
```

Comment: does a "yes" always go together with an other product name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One way**:
You may use `np.subtract.accumulate` with `transform`

```
s = df['Is First?'].eq('Yes').cumsum()
df['value'] = ((df.Inbound + df.Outbound).where(df['Is First?'].eq('Yes'), df.Outbound)
                                         .groupby(s)
                                         .transform(np.subtract.accumulate))

Out[1749]:
  Product  Inbound  Outbound Is First?  value
0       A      115        10       Yes    125
1       A      220        20        No    105
2       A      200        24        No     81
3       A      402        52        No     29
4       B      313        40       Yes    353
5       B      434        12        No    341
6       B      321        43        No    298
7       C      343        23       Yes    366
8       C      120        16        No    350
```

---

**Another way**:
Assign value for `Yes`. Create groupid `s` to use for groupby. Groupby and shift `Outbound` to calculate cumsum, and subtract it from 'Yes' value of each group. Finally, use it to fillna.

```
df['value'] = (df.Inbound + df.Outbound).where(df['Is First?'].eq('Yes'))
s = df['Is First?'].eq('Yes').cumsum()
s1 = df.value.ffill() - df.Outbound.shift(-1).groupby(s).cumsum().shift()
df['value'] = df.value.fillna(s1)

Out[1671]:
  Product  Inbound  Outbound Is First?  value
0       A      115        10       Yes  125.0
1       A      220        20        No  105.0
2       A      200        24        No   81.0
3       A      402        52        No   29.0
4       B      313        40       Yes  353.0
5       B      434        12        No  341.0
6       B      321        43        No  298.0
7       C      343        23       Yes  366.0
8       C      120        16        No  350.0
```

Comment: Could make it even short if a new product always corresponds to a Yes:
`df.loc[df['Is First?'].eq('Yes'),'Value'] = df.Inbound + df.Outbound
df.loc[df['Is First?'].eq('No'), 'Value'] = df.Value.ffill()-df.Outbound.shift(-1).groupby(df.Product).cumsum().shift()`

Comment: ah, I see what you mean. I did consider `df.Product` for groupby. However, I decided against it because OP's logic never says about it. His logic solely mentions only values of `'Is First?'`, so I have to create `s` to use for groupby.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial task, the difficulty lies in the consecutive `No`s. It's necessary to group consecutive no's together, the code below should do,

```
col_sum = df.Inbound+df.Outbound

mask_no = df['Is First?'].eq('No')

mask_yes = df['Is First?'].eq('Yes')

consec_no = mask_yes.cumsum()

result = col_sum.groupby(consec_no).transform('first')-df['Outbound'].where(mask_no,0).groupby(consec_no).cumsum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df.loc[df['Is First?'].eq('Yes'),'Value']=df['Inbound']+df['Outbound']
df.loc[~df['Is First?'].eq('Yes'),'Value']=df['Value'].fillna(0).shift().cumsum()-df.loc[~df['Is First?'].eq('Yes'),'Outbound'].cumsum()
```

Comment: This is wrong because the 1st `cumsum` is calculated across `'Yes'` groups.

Answer (score 1):

Annotated numpy code:

```
## 1. line up values to sum

ob = -df["Outbound"].values
# get yes indices
fi, = np.where(df["Is First?"].values == "Yes")
# insert yes formula at yes positions
ob[fi] = df["Inbound"].values[fi] - ob[fi]

## 2. calculate block sums and subtract each from the
## first element of the **next** block

ob[fi[1:]] -= np.add.reduceat(ob,fi)[:-1]
# now simply taking the cumsum will reset after each block
df["Value"] = ob.cumsum()
```

Result:

```
  Product  Inbound  Outbound Is First?  Value
0       A      115        10       Yes    125
1       A      220        20        No    105
2       A      200        24        No     81
3       A      402        52        No     29
4       B      313        40       Yes    353
5       B      434        12        No    341
6       B      321        43        No    298
7       C      343        23       Yes    366
8       C      120        16        No    350
```